# Что здесь подлежащее?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно пишется: "Много людей пытал**о**сь что-то здесь отыскать, но никогда ничего не находил**о**." Или: "Много людей пытал**и**сь что-то здесь отыскать, но никогда ничего не находил**и**."

Comment: Офф-топ. Ник почти такой же как у меня. Nikola. На одну букву только отличается. Что-то не очень нравится мне это.

Comment: Ну, у Вас все-таки Николя — по-французски, а у данного пользователя — Никола, по-славянски. Все-таки, имя Николай достаточно распространенное.   
Обещаю, мы не будем вас двоих путать))

Answer (score 1):

**Согласование сказуемого со словами «много, столько, немало»**

Счетные местоименные наречия **столько, сколько, много, немного, мало, немало** согласуются ***исключительно со сказуемым в форме единственного числа***:

*Столько долгов накопилось! Довольно много народу пришло на лекцию. Немало знаменательных событий предшествовало этому дню.*

Такое требование содержится в академической **«Русской грамматике»**.

**Д. Э. Розенталь** **в «Справочнике по правописанию и литературной правке»** отмечает, что в последнее время ***форма множественного числа*** в подобных конструкциях «…встречавшаяся в прошлом редко, находит все большее распространение»: ***Сколько замученных работой калек помирают с голоду (М. Горький)***.[Здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters?rub=bolshinstvo)

Что касается **второй части** предложения, я совершенно разделяю Ваши сомнения. Именно в ней появляется неблагозвучие, когда используется глагол в форме среднего рода  единственного числа. А потому  в этом  предложении я использовала бы ***только форму множественного числа*** сказуемых при подлежащем МНОГО ЛЮДЕЙ.

Comment: Меня здесь больше смутила вторая часть предложения (это цитата, а не моя придумка). Получается, Отыскать что-то пыталось много людей, но никогда ничего не находило Кто? Что? Оно - много? Видимо, автор текста забыл во второй части добавить местоимение "они", что и вызывает некий диссонанс.

Comment: Офф-топ: "Офф-топ. Ник почти такой же как у меня. Nikola. На одну букву только отличается. Что-то не очень нравится мне это."
Никаких теорий заговоров, меня зовут Николай.

Comment: Я дополнила ответ, Nikola. Спасибо.